# What is the best way to clone HDD partitions of differences sizes?

Tags: hard-drive, clone

I have two HDDs: the first of 150gb (`/dev/sdc`) with 30gb in use, the second of 100gb (`/dev/sdd`). There are `sdc1` and `sdd1` partitions with the same format.

I want to clone the 30gb from the first disk to the second **with differences sizes**. What is the best way? Clone it with `dd` or with `cat`?

**Two possibilities**:

From the `sdc` disk:

```
dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/sdd
cat /dev/sdc >/dev/sdd
```

From the `sdc1` partition:

```
dd if=/dev/sdc1 of=/dev/sdd1
cat /dev/sdc1 >/dev/sdd1
```

---

**Other questions**:

Assuming that `/dev/sdd1` already exists with data, could I overwrite it?

Could it cause an error in a sector of the hdd `/dev/sdd`?

Comment: It's not possible to clone 150GB partition to 100GB destination drive*. You either want to copy the 30GB data to new partition or you have to shrink the 150GB partition first and than clone.

*in some corner cases it might work, but not worth consideration

Comment: @Cieniek Are you sure?

Comment: You will truncate everything that lies beyond the capacity of destination drive during the cloning attempt.

Comment: Thank you dude, how could I clone without problem?, I cant resize the first partition. @Cieniek

Comment: If you really need a clone of that 150GB partiton without shrinking it, you either have to find a bigger destination drive or clone in parts.

Comment: @Cieniek Ty dude, assuming that the partitions are structure same, could I use simply cp -ar /mnt/sdc (mount point) to /mnt/sdd (mountpoint), is it true?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50855/discussion-between-cieniek-and-milor123).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're doing *partition cloning* then the option to use would be:

```
dd if=/dev/sdc1 of=/dev/sdd1
cat /dev/sdc1 >/dev/sdd1
```

Now the *command* to use will depend on what you want to achieve:

1. `cat` advantages:

   - fast
   - excellent at handling text files
   - copying the content of a partition to a new unformatted partition
2. `dd` advantages:

   - has more options
   - handles binary files well
   - can be used to *copy n bytes or skip/seek*
   - lets you specify block size

Things to consider:

- Make sure both *source and destination* partitions are the same size.
  Generally if you just want to copy over then `cat` is ok, but for more options `dd` will suffice.
- Data will be overwritten with `cat`, but `dd` can avoid this (man dd for more info)

Additional information:

- http://www.tecmint.com/backup-or-clone-linux-partitions-using-cat-command/
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/dd-vs-cat-is-dd-still-relevant-these-days/12538#12538
- [How would I speed up a full disk dd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/523037/how-would-i-speed-up-a-full-disk-dd)
- https://superuser.com/questions/692588/can-cat-be-used-to-clone-a-partition

### Important:

It's not possible to clone a 150GB partition to a smaller 100GB destination drive*. You either want to copy smaller data (say 30GB) to new partition or you have to shrink the larger (150GB) partition first and then clone. Otherwise, you will truncate everything that lies beyond the capacity of destination drive during the cloning attempt.

*In some corner cases it might work, but not worth consideration.

Comment: Thank you bro, what happen if I try use `cat /dev/sdc >/dev/sdd` ?

Comment: The whole `dev` gets copied over but any _binaries_ won't fair so well if you used `cat`