# When installing Ubuntu, can I use the dd command to copy the image to my 1TB hard drive for subsequent insertion into another machine?

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, dd

Typically people are [installing Ubuntu using a USB drive or burned DVD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromImgFiles), but I don't have these.  I would rather just go with installing to the destination hard drive itself, make it bootable, and place it in the destination machine for boot.  I have a brand new 1TB drive for this purpose.

The destination machine is a Dell Workstation that previously running Windows 7 off of a RAID array (but those drives are now unplugged by me).

I have a microITX computer running Ubuntu 14 now, and want to simply install Ubuntu from an image onto a new 1TB drive, then insert this into the Dell Workstation and boot.

Is this possible by simply using the dd command, or more complicated?  Should I partition or modify the 1TB drive in any way before running the dd command to transfer the Ubuntu image over and make this disk bootable?  Is the Ubuntu image going to be a working system, or an "installer" image?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Terrible waste of a 1TB drive. The dd copy is a DVD image of just the installer and does not even create or destroys any partition table. You have to use dd to erase MBR so you can partition drive later. Better to use one of the installers to install to a partition, or do a full install and then create a folder for ISO and boot those from grub. http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation AND then https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

Comment: This is similar to https://askubuntu.com/questions/435694/can-i-dd-a-larger-drive-to-a-smaller-one/936556#936556 where copies both to and from different sizes are discussed.  The dd command to wipe the MBR and partition tables is shown.