# dd command clones 10MB and stops

Tags: hard-drive, dd, clone

I am trying to clone old windows 8 HDD disk to new SSD. Both have the same capacity: 250GB

The problem is that dd command stops quickly after copying 10MB only.

Here is the output:

```
root@x72j:~# dd if=/dev/sdd of=/dev/sdc bs=128M conv=notrunc,noerror
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
10485760 bytes (10 MB) copied, 0.384963 s, 27.2 MB/s
```

I even tried copying to /dev/null

```
root@x72j:~# dd if=/dev/sdd of=/dev/null bs=128M conv=notrunc,noerror
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
10485760 bytes (10 MB) copied, 0.00766644 s, 1.4 GB/s
```

Why it doesn't clone full disk?

Comment: Have you tried to just use a simple `dd if=/dev/sdd of=/dev/sdc` with no limiting arguments?  Here is an answer that talks to this subject:   Check out this answer for details:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/435694/can-i-dd-a-larger-drive-to-a-smaller-one/936556#936556

Answer (score 1):

For anyone experiencing the same issue, it is likely because you have actually created the "file" `/dev/sdd`

The virtual `/dev` parition is usually 10MB which is why the `dd` stops after 10MB.

Even if the "device" `/dev/sdd` later shows up, it will be blocked by the existing file.

Try `ls -la /dev/sd*` and you should see some anomalies.

Comment: i don't understand your response. Sorry

Comment: That was it for me...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
exec sudo -i
fdisk -l
umount /dev/sdd?
fsck -y /dev/sdd?
dd if=/dev/sdd of=/dev/sdc bs=1M conv=noerror,sync
```

Change **?** for the corresponding partition of `/dev/sdd`

Comment: thanks for the response but I am targeting the device sdd and not just its partition.

Answer (score 0):

Most dd commands can be replaced with cat.

E.g.:

```
cat /dev/sdd > /dev/sdc
```